# how to get textfield data in win32-gui perl

Tags: perl, textfield

hi i want to store textfield data in a variable but my code is not working 
here is my code

```
use Win32::GUI qw<>;

my $W1 = Win32::GUI::Window->new(
 -name  => "W1",
 -title => "First Window",
 -pos   => [ 100, 100 ],
 -size  => [ 300, 200 ],
);

$W1->AddButton(
 -name => "ButtonW1",
 -text => "Enter Chipname",
 -pos  => [ 87, 100 ],
 #-ok  => 1,
);

 $W1->AddTextfield(
  -name    => "chipfield",
  -left    =>  20,
  -top     =>  40,
  -width   => 250,
  -height  => 20,
   #  -prompt => ["Mix ",30],
  );

$W1->Show();
Win32::GUI::Dialog();
exit(0);


sub W1_Terminate { return -1; }

sub ButtonW1_Click {
    my $chipname = $W1->chipfield->Text();
    print $chipname;
}
```

please help me where is problem`enter code here`

Comment: I ran that and it worked. I changed the print statement to `print "\$chipname='$chipname'\n"`, and got out `$chipname='ABC'`. What's the problem? I did get a complaint: "Can't call method "STORE" on an undefined value during global destruction.", but not every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a Buffering problem. Add $|=1; before the print $chipname; statement and everything will be fine like so:

```
my $chipname = $W1->chipfield->Text();
$|=1;
print $chipname;
```

Or do what axeman suggested by changing

```
print $chipname;
```

to

```
print $chipname,"\n";
```

You might also want to take a look at this article: [Suffering from Buffering?](http://perl.plover.com/FAQs/Buffering.html)

Comment: you are right your solution working fine for me but it is give me an error 
"Can't call method "STORE" on an undefined value during global destruction."
this error comes when i close my W1 window  

after google search
now i am using $chipfield_name->GetLine(0);
that is working fine for mee and not giving "Can't call method "STORE" on an undefined value during global destruction."type of error.

thanks for your reply :)

Comment: @amit, you're welcome :) the code works and exits fine on my computer (ActiveState Perl 5.10.0 WinXP SP3) without the "Can't call method STORE" error. And yes GetLine(0) can also get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a problem of destroy pocessing of "Win32::GUI::Window Class"

```
my $W1 = Win32::GUI::Window->new(
 -name  => "W1",
 -title => "First Window",
 -pos   => [ 100, 100 ],
 -size  => [ 300, 200 ],
);
...

$W1->Show();
Win32::GUI::Dialog();
undef $W1;       <-----Addtion line
exit(0);
```